# JS - Waiting for other function to do its job before moving forward

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with waiting till some things are done in the function that is being called inside a **for loop**.

I have several Divs stored in an array and the thing I want to achieve is:

1. One randomly chosen div highlights for 1s
2. After the previously chosen div stops highlighting some other randomly chosen div starts to do the same thing

So I want to make them highlight in a random sequence.

I have been trying different things from the internet, however can't make it to work the way it should. Usually the loop just go through all the divs and there is no waiting or anything. They are all highlighted at the same time.

The code below has promise with which I was trying to achieve the final goal, but I am not pretty sure if it is the correct approach. I have also tried using **await/async**, but probably I don't know how to use them properly, so it didn't work.

```
function startHiglightingBlocks()
    {
        sequenceDivs = [];
        var randomIndexes = shuffle(indexes);
        clickIndex = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < sequenceLength; ++i)
        {
            sequenceDivs.push(blockDivs[randomIndexes[i]]);
            highlightBlock(blockDivs.eq(randomIndexes[i]))
                    .then(
                        function (result) {
                            
                        }
                    );
        }
    }

    function highlightBlock(block)
    {
        block.addClass('highlight');
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                block.removeClass('highlight');
                block.text(i)
                resolve("Success");
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you also post your async/await code?

Comment: Although it seems like everyone wants to find a reason to use promises, they aren't always needed. Instead of a promise, just pass your callback function as the second parameter of `highlightBlock` and call that function within your setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this example.

```js
const shuffle = (array) => {
  const result = Array.from({
    length: array.length
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)) | 0;

    if (j !== i) {
      result[i] = result[j];
    };

    result[j] = array[i];
  }

  return result;
};

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const highlight = async(elements) => {
  const sequence = shuffle(elements);

  for (let element of sequence) {
    element.classList.add('highlight');
    await delay(1000);
    element.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
};

highlight(document.querySelectorAll('div')).then(() => console.log('done!'));
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Cat</div>
<div>Fish</div>
<div>Dog</div>
<div>Bird</div>
```

This is using a `for of` loop with `async/await` as you mentioned in one of your attempts, I think its a good approach with few lines without having to manage state.

As you can see we just pass our selected `elements` into `highlight`. This will `shuffle` them then and start processing the timeline. Really the only magic here is the `delay` function. Which returns an async task that will complete after some amount of ms. Given our `delay` function and `async/await` we can simply add a `class` to our current element, wait 1000ms, and remove the class, and continue the loop. A nice pro of using `async/await` in this fashion is you can actually `await` or `then` the entire `highlight` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried to follow your code and your description and I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps but this code doesn't use async/await:

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");

//function to choose a random number within [min,max] range
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
 //fuction to change background-color
function highlight(index) {
  divs[index].style.backgroundColor = "mediumseagreen";
}

setTimeout(function run() {
  let randomIndex = random(0, divs.length - 1);
  highlight(randomIndex);
  setTimeout(() => {
    divs[randomIndex].style.backgroundColor = "lightgray";
    run();
  }, 1000);
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Sometimes it seems the highlighted div keeps the new colour for more than 1s, that's because two consecutive chosen random numbers are the same.